# How to go about this non-linear eigenvector problem

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, nonlinear-system

I have these non-linear coupled differential equations:
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}A_1}{\mathrm{d}z} = C_1 A_1^* A_2 \\
\frac{\mathrm{d}A_2}{\mathrm{d}z} = C_2 A_1^2
$$
Where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are constants and $A_1$ and $A_2$ vary in $z$.

Basically, what I'd like to do is, write those two equations in the form (or something similar):
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}
\begin{bmatrix}
  A_1 \\
  A_2  
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
  a & b \\
  c & d
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  A_1 \\
  A_2  
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I'm after finding the eigenvectors/eigenvalues of the system.  Any advice on how to proceed is appreciated.

My current idea is to some how linearise the system using a Taylor Series approach; I believe these types of systems are normally linearised about a steady-state condition; however, I believe the solution to this is sinusoidal, and so I'm not sure about what point to linearise.  I believe I might be able to somehow linearise about a sinusoid using Fourier theory, though not sure.

Thank you.

Comment: Are the capital variables supposed to be matrices?  Can't you solve the first equation for $A_2$ and plug that into the second equation?

Comment: None of the variables are matrices.  And yes, you're right, I can solve the equations like that, but I'm not after solving it, rather, I'm after the eigenmodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to determine eigenmodes you must employ some kind of linearisation, that is the most basic idea is to choose some point $(A_{10},A_{20})$ and then determine the linear system of equations that enables you to determine eigenmodes of your system, but limited only to the short interval around the chosen point.

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}A_1}{\mathrm{d}t} = C_1 A_1^* A_2 \\
\frac{\mathrm{d}A_2}{\mathrm{d}t} = C_2 A_1^2 $$

So we choose some point $(A_{10},A_{20})$ and linearise:

$$ \frac{dA_1}{dt}=f_1(A_1,A_2)$$
$$ \frac{d\Delta A_1}{dt}=\frac{df_1}{dA_1}|_{A_{10},A_{20}}\Delta A_1+\frac{df_1}{dA_2}|_{A_{10},A_{20}}\Delta A_2$$

$$ \frac{dA_2}{dt}=f_2(A_1,A_2)$$
$$ \frac{d\Delta A_2}{dt}=\frac{df_2}{dA_1}|_{A_{10},A_{20}}\Delta A_1+\frac{df_2}{dA_2}|_{A_{10},A_{20}}\Delta A_2$$

This enables us to determine:

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}
\begin{bmatrix}
  A_1 \\
  A_2  
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
  a & b \\
  c & d
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  A_1 \\
  A_2  
\end{bmatrix} $$

with $a,b,c,d$ being the linearisation coefficients calculated from the upper partial derivations.

$$ \frac{d\Delta A_1}{dt}=C_1A_{20}\Delta A_1+C_1 A_{10}\Delta A_2$$

$$ \frac{d\Delta A_2}{dt}=2C_2 A_{10}\Delta A_1+0\Delta A_2$$

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}
\begin{bmatrix}
  \Delta A_1 \\
  \Delta A_2  
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
  C_1 A_{20} & C_1A_{10} \\
  2C_2 A_{10} & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  \Delta A_1 \\
  \Delta A_2  
\end{bmatrix} $$

From this point on you can determine eigenvectors and eigenmodes of the system, although it would be helpful we had more info on the system, is it some kind of physical system or control system, or something like that...

Comment: Hi, thank you for that!  I didn't add much context to avoid confusion, but basically (and I'm an electrical engineering student) the coupled differential equations I wrote above model the transfer of photon population in a non-linear optical crystal between a fundamental frequency, and it's second harmonic (given that the system is phase matched).  $A_1$ represents the amplitude of the fundamental and $A_2$ represents the amplitude of the second harmonic.  I then get the 2x2 matrix (call it $M$) and put it into Shrodinger's equation ($dA/dz = j M A$).  The eigenvectors of $M$ represent the

Comment: modes in the waveguide, and the eigenvalues sort of represent the effective refractive index each of those modes 'sees'.  The off diagonal terms in $M$ represent the rate at which the population from one mode transfer to another.  I am trying to work out whether the above system will have any eigenvectors (given it is nonlinear) and I believe the eigenvalues keep changing but at steady state, the eigenvalues become constant and thus the eigenmodes are constant.  I know this is similar to control systems problems, so I tried to relate it to that, though I don't really do control.

Comment: Nonlinear systems have a complex dynamics, and not all steady states represent stability points, you could check something like this:

http://homepages.ulb.ac.be/~dgonze/TEACHING/nonlinear.pdf